# How to make text moves up relative to another View - android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am writing an app that has a chat. I have a task to make a `RecyclerView`, which will contain messages from me or from another user with whom I am in dialogue.

I need to display a round icon with a person's profile, and to the right of it the message text.

The message consists of the name and the text of the message itself. How can I make my text "move" up relative to the profile icon depending on the size of the message?

How it should look can be seen on the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: You should post the XML.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's a bit hard to give an answer without seeing your code. Please edit your question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your round icon :

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="{your_text_container}"
```

This line tells the round icon to always stay at the bottom of your text, also don't forget to wrap your views with a `ConstraintLayout`.